# RethinkDB 'make' fails on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: gcc, raspberry-pi, rethinkdb

I have tried running the 'make ALLOW_WARNINGS=1' command multiple times, but it seems to fail every time.

I have made sure gcc is updated and so is the rethinkDB package.

Here's the error it produces:

[image: RethinkDB make failing]

Comment: Hey D4RKVIPER33, are you running this on a Raspberry Pi 2 per chance?

Comment: No, A Raspberry Pi Model A

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was down to the fact I didn't have enough swap. I ordered a new RPi2 and it worked (due to 1GB of ram built in), but I also found out that I didn't increase the swap file on the RPi1 correctly, I was following this [tutorial](http://snippets.khromov.se/increase-or-add-swap-file-raspberry-pi/) and I didn't carry out the last two commands, so it might still be possible on a RPi1, I haven't checked.

Comment: Ah yes, it definitely is possible. I followed this guide for reference => https://www.bitpi.co/2015/02/11/how-to-change-raspberry-pis-swapfile-size-on-rasbian/